# Laravel 5 belongsTo relation in same table chaining

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model like this

```
Document [id, text, previous_document_id]
```

And when I retrieve data, I can use this relation:

```
public function previous()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document', 'previous_document_id');
    }
```

to get a document with it's previous document.
But there is a situation like this: *document->previous_document->previous_document* and so on.
How can I get this chain ?
**Edit:**
I don't know how many previous documents exist

**Edit2:**
***Solution is:***

```
public function previous()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document', 'previous_document_id')->with('previous');
}
```

Comment: You can chain the relationship: `$document->previous->previous->previous`

Comment: But how can I know how many previous documents original document have?

Comment: There are packages that can help you manage nested tree structures. E.g. https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: Otherwise, you could use a `while` loop to keep looking for the previous document, until the value is `null`.

Comment: You can add `->with('previous')` to your relationship. Then `Document::with('previous')->get()` will load the whole chain.

Comment: Nested structure prefer
Look at this package, thanks

Comment: -> Then Document::with('previous')->get() will load the whole chain.   
Doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Did you change the relationship to `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document', 'previous_document_id')->with('previous');`?

Comment: Oops...it was so easy...facepalm  
Thanks!